# Thread.Join appears to return false incorrectly

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using [`Thread.Join(int millisecondsTimeout)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b1kkss0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to terminate a number of `AppDomain`s.

Frequently, I get an error message stating that the AppDomain did not terminate within 5 seconds.  Whilst stepping through the debugger I see that the `AppDomain.Unload()` call terminates easily within 5 seconds, but `Thread.Join` returns false.

Where am I going wrong?

```
var thread = new Thread(
    () =>
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(someAppDomain);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {

        }
        catch (CannotUnloadAppDomainException exception)
        {
            // Some error message
        }
    });

thread.Start();
const int numSecondsWait = 5;

if (!thread.Join(1000 * numSecondsWait))
{
    // Some error message about it not exiting in 5 seconds
}
```

**Edit 1**

Worth adding what each of the `AppDomain`s do.  Each `AppDomain` has at least one [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).  The code roughly looks as follows, (keep in mind I've collapsed loads of classes into one here for readability).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _exceptionThrown = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    _timer = new Timer(TickAction, null, 0, interval);
    try
    {
        _exceptionThrown.WaitOne();
    }
    finally
    {
        _timer.Dispose(_timerWaitHandle);
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(_timerWaitHandle);
    }
}
```

In effect I know that the "Main" thread will throw a [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx), jump into the finally statement and ensure the `Timer` queue is fully drained before exiting.

All of the `Timer`s though log when they are inside the tick method.  So I can be near certain that there is nothing on the timer queue, and the `_timer.Dispose(_timerWaitHandle)` returns immediately.

Regardless of whether it does or not, at least *one* of the three `AppDomain`s I am `Unload`ing will not complete it within 5 seconds.

Comment: Apparently `AppDomain.Unload` [already has some threading stuff going on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx); could it be something to do with that?

Comment: @Rawling unfortunately it is inside `mscorelib` with an `InternalCall`, can't really see what `AppDomain.nUnload(int domainInternal)` is doing.  The fact that it calls this in a dedicated thread, I just can't see why that would be a problem.  What's not clear is whether `AppDomain.Unload` is synchronous (it seems to be), and therefore multiple unloads on the same `Unload` thread could easily surpass the 5 seconds.

Comment: Side note: "stepping in debugger" with heavily threaded code would not give you much information about timings... Consider adding StopWatch and tracing to really know how long it takes.

Comment: What's the state of the thread when the join times out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be sure that the appdomains always unload within 5 seconds, you can try to measure it.
For example using something like this:

```
var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
AppDomain.Unload(someAppDomain);
long elapsedMillis = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Writeline("Unload duration: " + elapsedMillis + " ms");
```

The Output window of Visual Studio (or the DebugView tool from sysinternals) should show it

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is well documented in the MSDN Library article for Unload():

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0 there is a thread dedicated to unloading application domains. This improves reliability, especially when the .NET Framework is hosted. When a thread calls Unload, the target domain is marked for unloading. The dedicated thread attempts to unload the domain, and all threads in the domain are aborted. **If a thread does not abort**, for example because it is executing unmanaged code, or because it is executing a finally block, then after a period of time a CannotUnloadAppDomainException is thrown in the thread that originally called Unload. If the thread that could not be aborted eventually ends, the target domain is not unloaded. Thus, in the .NET Framework version 2.0 domain is not guaranteed to unload, because it might not be possible to terminate executing threads.
>
> The threads in domain are terminated using the Abort method, which throws a ThreadAbortException in the thread. Although the thread should terminate promptly, it can continue executing for an unpredictable amount of time in a finally clause.

So you'll need to find out why your program has a thread running inside that appdomain and why it refuses to abort.  Common for example when it is buried inside non-managed code.  Use Debug + Windows + Threads to see them.

Comment: +1... To debug try both CLR and Mixed mode debugging, and may even need WinDbg. In most confusing cases grab full dump (or several) instead of debugging immediately...