# Entity Framework 6 update-database throws error while unloading appdomain

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have an EF6 application that is currently using automatic migrations. Our `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class is:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

This has all been working fine for a few months, somewhere in the last week it has started to throw an error whilst seeding. I have looked through all the change sets (a fair few), and can not see anything that has changed on the context object or configuration that might have effected this. There are no external DLL's being called.

The seeding will always run but at the end it will throw:

> System.CannotUnloadAppDomainException: Error while unloading appdomain.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)
>   at System.AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain domain)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Dispose()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>
> Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)

If I remove any use of the context object from the seeding it will work fine.

If I even do:

```
var objs = context.ObjectX.ToList();
```

It will throw the error.

I have tried remove all references to EF, deleting the packages and re-downloading them, deleting the database, using a new database but it will always throw the error.

I am not sure how to track down what is causing this. Any thoughts / processes / ideas on how to handle / fix / track down this would be great.

Comment: Hi Jon - see the source https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Design/ToolingFacade.cs - when looking for migration classes, it loads them into its own AppDomain.  When finished it uploads the appdomain.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.cannotunloadappdomainexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 says there are 3 reasons for the exception - it must be the 2nd or 3rd. Already unloaded (disposing twice?) or a running thread.  No threads created, so maybe it's disposed twice?

Comment: Could also be something to do with static (or other) constructors in the migrations type doing something long-running?  Or something that they depend on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Opening out my comment)

Happily you can see the source at https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Design/ToolingFacade.cs - when looking for migration classes, it loads them into its own AppDomain. When finished it uploads the appdomain.

The exception documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.cannotunloadappdomainexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, says there are 3 reasons for the exception - it must be the 2nd or 3rd. Already unloaded (disposing twice?) or a running thread. No threads created, so maybe it's disposed twice?

It could also be something to do with static (or other) constructors in the migrations type doing something long-running? Or something that they depend on.

Comment: turned out to be a custom attribute on the class.  oddly the DLL for ithas not changed in a good while and the attribute has been there for a long time, which is why I didnt think that would have had an effect.  You answer lead me down the path to check it out.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

[`HRESULT: 0x80131015` for such errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398066/213550) means that you got something wrong into your `COM` part of code. As you can see from stacktrace, the error is being rised during `MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute`.

So the problem is that your data doesn't being sent correctly to the server or `MigrationsDomainCommand` didn't recieve success result from database in some amount of time.

May be your application tries to migrate to much data, or something? Check the `timeout` for your connection **AND** command - they have different timeouts by default. Or may be it simply trying to use a disposed command or collection.

Comment: Hi VMAtm, thx for the reply.  I have no COM calls (at least none that we have created, there could be some from EF).  dont believe it could be a timeout, as if I take all the seeding data out and just do 1 select it will still fail.

Comment: @Jon May be there are some transport issues? May be SQL-connection being pooled?

Comment: unlikely, but possible.  Happens on four machines (all that I have tested).  Each of which have their own DB.  The connection string hasnt changed in the configuration.

Comment: @Jon Do you use `TransactionScope`? This can lead to a distributed transaction across your DB and some outer resource. May be cache or session storage?

Comment: we don't.  simply access the context directly, no transactions or unit of work stuff setup yet.

Comment: @Jon Hmmm, very strange. Did you check the network traffic during the exception?

Comment: This isn't it - the app domain used by ToolingFacade doesn't create any threads